# What is the error in multiplication of long long Integer?

Tags: c, memory, int, long-integer

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
     long long int t=8*9*100000000;// 8 zeros
     printf("%lld\n",t);
     return 0;
 }
```

**gives result:** `-1389934592`

---

please reply

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
     long long int t=8*9*1000000000; //9zeros
     printf("%lld\n",t);
     return 0;
 }
```

**gives result:** `-1014444032`

---

while all other multiplication gave correct result i.e.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
     long long int t=8*9*10000000000; //10zeros or greater or zeros <=6
     printf("%lld\n",t);
     return 0;
 }
```

**gives result:** `720000000000`

---

Comment: Undefined behaviour because of signed int overflow is undefined. Anything can happen. Use LL with your literals.

Comment: Try this: `8LL*9LL*1000000000LL` (9 zeros)

Comment: I think is better to talk about rounded results more than undefined behaviour, the results is logically defined by the operators type dimension because the compiler consider 100,000,000 as a 32 bit integer, instead of 64 bit as the type of long long int t. The behavior is the same if you use `t=8 * 9* k;`,where k is `int k=100000000;`

Comment: @SergioFormiggini Rounding occurs with floating point numbers, integers are not rounded at all. And while this result is logical to us, on non-twocomplement devices or with different variable sizes, the result will be different. It´s specified as *undefined* for a reason.

Comment: Ok! Received! ,,, I've not considered the non-twocomplement devices! :p (With rounding I meant truncation, but your explanation clears me that is better to consider this situation in general as an undefined behaviour)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`100000000` with 8 zeros or `1000000000` with 9 zeros fit into an 32bit `int` (`long`, not `long long`), and that´s the default. Then the multiplications are made with 32bit `int`´s,
and **then** the result gets converted to 64bit.
This is a problem because the result won´t fit into 32bit => Overflow.

With the with 10 zeros, you´ll have an 64bit `int` from the start,
because this number won´t fit into an 32bit `int`.
=> Calculations are done with 64bit, no problem.

If you want the 8-zero and 9-zero number to be used as `long long`, use `LL`, 
ie. `100000000LL`

Answer (score 4):

```
8*9*1000000000; //9zeros
```

is (32bit) * (32bit) * (32bit) --> the answer is put into 32bit
while

```
8*9*10000000000; //10zeros
```

is (32bit) * (32bit) * (64bit) --> the answer is put info 64bit